# Is it possible to add a RemoteViews to a LinearLayout in Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-linearlayout, remoteview

I'd want to show a preview of my widget (or notification) in my Activity but I don't want to use other code.

Is it possible to add a RemoteViews to a LinearLayout in Activity or trasform a RemoteViews in a simple View to use the method "addView" of LinearLayout?

Many thanks at all!